# jsp pass Vietnamese to java class file

Tags: java, encoding, special-characters, utf, alphabet

Good day,

I tried to google on this, but fail to get any related suggestion/solution. I think my question maybe misleading.

In my jsp page, I have a input text-area box:

```
<s:textarea name="errorMessage.message" maxlength="500"/>
```

When I click on update button, my java application will get this `errorMessage.message` and store into db.

This is working fine if user key in english character. But if I key in Vietnamese, it will turn to other weird symbol in my Java file.

For example, user input `siêu nhân`, it will turn become `siÃªu nhÃ¢n`.

```
String test = getRequest( ).getParameter( "errorMessage.message" );
System.out.println("errorMessage.message is " + test);
// It will print out "errorMessage.message is siÃªu nhÃ¢n" in my console.
```

But If I hard code it in java file, then its working fine and I can store the Vietnamese correctly into db also.

```
errorMessage.setMessage( "siêu nhân" );

System.out.println("now message is " + errorMessage.getMessage( )); \\ this print correctly in my console
```

I has been tried :

```
getRequest().setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" );

<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

But still the same issue, kindly advise.

Comment: Which jar are you using to connect to db2 **db2jcc4.jar** or **db2jcc4.jar** ?

Comment: @Shaunak, I only use `db2jcc4.jar` when run the spring batch. In Web application level, I believe that I am connecting to db2 by configure the setting in IBM WAS console, in `Resources`, `JDBC` level.

Comment: Looks like an UTF-8 transform is being applied.The ISO character set can't represent all the multi-accented characters. E.g. `Phở` will show as `Phá»Ÿ`.
Make sure your app stores and displays the string as UTF-8

Comment: @Stavr00 , May I know where/how to control my app to stores and displays the String as UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I get some solution:

Solution 1 (Only applicable for 1 input):

```
 try {
      byte[] bytes = test.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
      test = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    } catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Solution 2 (Apply for whole system):

I am using WAS, so go to WAS console, Application servers > SITSMESCAPP01a > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine,

Add `-Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8` into Generic JVM arguments.

Restart server.